Book about a boy and girl whose family believe the world will end and need to meet at a mountain top
Don't remember much more. Just that it's a church or a cult that believes the world is ending or the leader believes they need to meet at mountain top on a certain night. If I remember right, the main characters are a boy and girl in the congregation.

In roughly which year did you read this? And did the story contain any definite sci-fi or fantasy elements? Like, was the world actually ending, or were the people believing that mistaken?

No fantasy that I remember. Didn't remember withered it ended or not. Just remembered the 2 kids come from problems and maybe it involved love interest. Someone posted the answer, soon as I saw the cover and title I knew it was that one

Possibly Armageddon Summer by Jane Yolen and Bruce Coville?


The world will end on Thursday, July 27, 2000. At least, that’s what Reverend Beelson has told his congregation. That’s why Marina and Jed and their parents have joined the rest of the Reverend’s flock at a mountain retreat to await the end of the world. But this world has only just begun for Jed and Marina, two teenagers with more attitude than faith. Why should the world end now, when they’ve just fallen in love for the first time?

It fits your description, though I suspect there will be many books that match.

Yes! That's the one, thank you so much.

Sounds like at least they had more fun than the Millerites.
